# VB.NET Can't send POST request properly

Tags: json, string, vb.net, dictionary, post

So I'm using Newtonsoft.Json to send POST requests.

I have to use the Dictionary to specify my key and value.

Here is how the POST should look like on the receiving end:

```
{"type":"direct","packages":["http://whatever:9999/something.pkg"]}
```

My code:

```
    dictData.Add("type", "direct")
    dictData.Add("packages", "[http://whatever:9999/something.pkg]")
    jsonPost.postData(dictData)
```

And the output:

```
 {
  "type": "direct",
  "packages": "[http://whatever:9999/something.pkg]"
   }
```

So the issues: I want no spaces in there, I want it all in one line, and I want the URL in quotation marks. I tried the double "" method, and I got my quotation marks, but it also placed a \ to both the beginning and end of the URL.

I'm sure it is something simple, but for the life of me I could not find anything that worked.

Comment: Try passing the packages value as an array or list of string instead of as a scalar string, e.g. `dictData.Add("packages", {"http://whatever:9999/something.pkg"})`.  The position of the brackets indicates that it should be treated as a list (with one member) instead of a scalar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply create a Jobject (first {} ) and add stuff to it. Like:

```
Dim JSON_Post As New JObject
JSON_Post.Add("type", "direct")
Dim JSON_Array As New JArray
JSON_Array.Add("http://whatever:9999/something.pkg")
'Or JSON_Post.Add("packages", New JArray From {"http://whatever:9999/something.pkg"})
JSON_Post.Add("packages", JSON_Array)
Debug.Print(JSON_Post.ToString)

'Output
{
  "type": "direct",
  "packages": [
    "http://whatever:9999/something.pkg"
  ]
}
```

You could do the same with dictionary and list, dictionary is key-value part so it would always look like

```
"type1": "direct1",
"type2", "direct2"...
```

So you need to add something with more items (at once), like a list to get the [].

And those spaces are not important, it will be read just fine, it's just how display is formatted.